# Get the path of folder inside my JSF Project

Tags: jsf

I´m developing a project and have a class that validate xml files, but they come from webPage, and downloaded from a webmail and save in the temporary folder.

My problem is, If I get the files by application, I can get my xsd files to validate. But by email download they don´t load my files.

But how can I get theses files in my resources folders?

```
public static String xsdFile(File file) {

    String rootElement = getRootElement(file);
    String rootVersion = getVersion(file);
    String realPath = ""; 

    try {
        realPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(xsdPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String path = XmlUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath().replaceAll("classes/", "");
        path  = path.concat(xsdPath).concat(rootVersion).concat("/").concat(rootElement).concat(".xsd");
        File teste = new File(path);

        if (teste.exists()) {
            System.out.println("found");
        }
        return path.concat ("/").concat(rootVersion).concat("/").concat(rootElement).concat(".xsd");
    }
    return realPath.concat("\\").concat(rootVersion).concat("\\").concat(rootElement).concat(".xsd");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String xsdFile(File file) {

    String rootElement = getRootElement(file);
    String rootVersion = getVersion(file);
    String realPath = "";

    try {

        realPath = getHTTPpath();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return getMachinePath(rootVersion, rootElement).concat(".xsd");

    }

    return realPath.concat("\\").concat(rootVersion).concat("\\").concat(rootElement).concat(".xsd");
}

private static String getHTTPpath() throws Exception {
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath(xsdPath);
}

private static String getMachinePath(String rootVersion, String rootElement) {

    String realPath = XmlUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath();

    try {

        realPath = URLDecoder.decode(realPath, "UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    realPath = realPath.substring(1).replace("/WEB-INF/classes", "");
    return realPath.concat("resources/xsd/" + rootVersion + "/" + rootElement);
}
```